# ProgressBar and AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I currently have an AsyncTask running that updates the progress bar inside the Activity while downloading a file. The problem is when i leave the Activity and reenters, the ProgressBar will not update anymore.

I tried running the AsyncTask inside a Service but i have no idea how to send the ProgressBar value back to my Activity's UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the same problem as you did:

- I wanted an async task executed (as service)
- I wanted to be able to rotate the device, be able to update the UI even if the task finished while the screen was off and I got no notification.

I came up with something like:

```
public class DatabaseIncompleteActivity extends RoboActivity {
private BroadcastReceiver       receiver;
private ProgressDialog          progressDialog;

@Inject
private DatabaseSetManager      databaseSetManager;
@Inject
private DatabaseDownloadLogger  databaseDownloadLogger;

private LocalBroadcastManager   localBroadcastManager;
private String                  jobId;

private static final int        ERROR_RETRY_DIALOG  = 1;
private static final String     ERROR_MESSAGE       = "errorMsg";

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( this );

    showProgressDialog();
    if ( getLastNonConfigurationInstance() == null ) {
        startService();
    }
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog( this );
    progressDialog.setMessage( getString( R.string.please_wait ) );
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle( ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL );
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate( true );
    progressDialog.setCancelable( false );
    progressDialog.show();
}

private void startService() {
    this.jobId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, ClientDatabaseDroidService.class );
    intent.putExtra(    ClientDatabaseDroidService.JOB_ID,
                        jobId );
    intent.putExtra(    ClientDatabaseDroidService.INTERACTIVE,
                        true );
    startService( intent );
}

private void registerListenerReceiver() {
    if ( receiver != null ) {
        return;
    }
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver( this.receiver = new ClientDatabaseBroadcastReceiver(),
                                            new IntentFilter( ClientDatabaseDroidService.PROGRESS_NOTIFICATION ) );
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterListenerReceiver();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    DatabaseDownloadLogEntry logEntry = databaseDownloadLogger.findByJobId( jobId );
    // check if service finished while we were not listening
    if ( logEntry != null ) {
        if ( logEntry.isSuccess() )
            onFinish();
        else {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(   ERROR_MESSAGE,
                                logEntry.getErrorMessage() );
            onError( bundle );
        }
        return;
    }

    registerListenerReceiver();
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}

final class ClientDatabaseBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        int eventType = extras.getInt( ClientDatabaseDroidService.EVENT_TYPE );

        switch ( eventType ) {
        case ClientDatabaseDroidService.EVENT_TYPE_DOWNLOADING:
            onDownloading( extras );
            break;
        case ClientDatabaseDroidService.EVENT_TYPE_FINISHED:
            onFinish();
            break;
        case ClientDatabaseDroidService.EVENT_TYPE_ERROR:
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(   ERROR_MESSAGE,
                                extras.getString( ClientDatabaseDroidService.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE ) );
            onError( bundle );
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException( "should not happen" );
        }
    }

}

private void unregisterListenerReceiver() {
    if ( receiver != null ) {
        localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver( receiver );
        receiver = null;
    }
}

private void onError( Bundle extras ) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    showDialog( ERROR_RETRY_DIALOG,
                extras );
}

private void onFinish() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    setResult( RESULT_OK );
    finish();
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( final int id, Bundle args ) {
    if ( id == ERROR_RETRY_DIALOG ) {
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
        builder.setTitle( R.string.error );
        builder.setMessage( "" );
        builder.setPositiveButton(  R.string.yes,
                                    new OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
                                            showProgressDialog();
                                            startService();
                                        }
                                    } );
        builder.setNegativeButton(  R.string.no,
                                    new OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
                                            setResult( RESULT_CANCELED );
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    } );
        return builder.create();
    }

    return super.onCreateDialog(    id,
                                    args );
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog( int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args ) {
    if ( id == ERROR_RETRY_DIALOG ) {
        ( (AlertDialog) dialog ).setMessage( String.format( "%s\n\n%s",
                                                            args.getString( ERROR_MESSAGE ),
                                                            getString( R.string.do_you_wish_to_retry ) ) );
        return;
    }

    super.onPrepareDialog(  id,
                            dialog );
}

private void onDownloading( Bundle extras ) {
    String currentDatabase = extras.getString( ClientDatabaseDroidService.EXTRA_CURRENT_CLASSIFIER );
    Progress databaseProgress = extras.getParcelable( ClientDatabaseDroidService.EXTRA_DATABASE_PROGRESS );
    Progress downloadProgress = extras.getParcelable( ClientDatabaseDroidService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS );
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate( false );
    progressDialog.setMessage( String.format(   "[%d/%d] %s",
                                                databaseProgress.getProcessed(),
                                                databaseProgress.getSize(),
                                                currentDatabase ) );
    progressDialog.setProgress( (int) downloadProgress.getProcessed() );
    progressDialog.setMax( (int) downloadProgress.getSize() );
}
```

}

The main idea is:

- The activity communicates with service via broadcast. The following events are dispatched from service to UI: download progress (reported each x bytes), download finished, error occured
- Each activity start is being assigned a unique job ID which is kept for screen rotation.
- Each job result is being persisted into database (or any other persistent storage). This way I can get the job result even if broadcast received was not listening at the moment (screen was off).

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make in your activity static progress variable
2. Save progress to preferences

When you re-enter activity grab and set progress from static variable or preferences.

Comment: but if i save the progress to preferences and set it from either the static variable or preferences wouldn't the progressBar be stuck at the progress that was saved inside the static variable/preferences?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Activities die when you leave them or rotate your device. Then they are recreated. AsyncTasks don't relink to the new Activity instance automatically.

Actually, [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) is the library you are looking for : it will allow you to launch a download from an activity, rotate the device, leave the activity, even leave the app, even kill it using the task switcher and your download will survive. Any activity, a new instance of your former activity, or even a completely different one will be able to relink to your download.

You should download the app [RoboSpice Motivations](http://goo.gl/pzqH4) from the store, it will explain you why it's not a good idea to use AsyncTasks for networking and show you how to use RoboSpice.

To get a good & fast overview of this problem, please have a look at [this infographics](http://goo.gl/jxNin).

Also note that if you only download binary data and are not interested in POJOs for instance, then you can use RoboSpice still or the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) (but it's API is less intuitive than RoboSpice).